# useContext not updating its value in callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, closures, react-hooks

`useConext` value is not updating in my callback attached to `wheel` event. I tried to console but still printing static value. But outside the callback, it's printing updated value

```
const Home = () => {
  //accessing my context
  var [appState, dispatch] = useContext(CTX);
  //printing updated value here (working perfect here)
  console.log(appState);

  //my callback on wheel event (also using debouce to queue burst of events)
  var fn = debounce(e => {
    //incrementing value ++1
    dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_COMPONENT_COUNTER' });
    //printing static value here (problem here)
    console.log(appState);
  }, 500);

  //setting and removing listener on component mount and unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('wheel', fn);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', fn);
    };
  }, []);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

On mounting, the listener initialized with a function variable which encloses the first value of `appStore` in its lexical scope.

Refer to [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

To fix it, move it into `useEffect` scope.

```
const Home = () => {
  const [appState, dispatch] = useContext(CTX);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fn = debounce(e => {
      dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_COMPONENT_COUNTER' });

      console.log(appState);
    }, 500);

    window.addEventListener('wheel', fn);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', fn);
    };
  }, [appState]);
};
```

Friendly advice:

- Use [linter like `eslint`](https://eslint.org/) - It should have warned you of using `appState` inside `useEffect`
- [Don't use `var`](https://www.google.com/search?q=dont%20use%20var&oq=dont%20use%20var&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1248j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - it's error-prone.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on why the original solution doesn't work? Does that mean appState is mutated every time dispatch is called? (ie., appState is not a pointer and therefore it always contains the original value).

Comment: There is a closure on `appState` so its value is stale on next render

Comment: Hmm yes, but if appState was a pointer that wouldn't be a problem because appState itself would be unchanged but the value it points to would. I'm not sure to really understand what is happening here.

Comment: Even if its a "pointer"  `appState={someValue}`, if the `appState` object will change: `appState={someValue, otherValue}` the value in the listener will be stale.

Comment: So if I get it correctly, `dispatch` is modifying `appState`'s value and not the object itself which is why it doesn't work? (here is [my question](https://repl.it/join/abanzryn-christianglacet) without the ambiguity)

Comment: I don't know how `dispatch` implemented, the "not working" part is that he always logs the same `appState` value.

Answer (score 0):

Your debance function is changing in every render, while the useEffect have the capture of only the first render, you can fix this with a useCallback:

```
const Home = () => {
  // accessing my context
  const [appState, dispatch] = useContext(CTX)
  // printing updated value here (working perfect here)
  console.log(appState)

  // my callback on wheel event (also using debouce to queue burst of events)
  const fn = useCallback(
    () =>
      debounce(e => {
        // incrementing value ++1
        dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_COMPONENT_COUNTER' })
        // printing static value here (problem here)
        console.log(appState)
      }, 500),
    [appState, dispatch],
  )

  // setting and removing listener on component mount and unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('wheel', fn)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', fn)
    }
  }, [fn])
}
```

Comment: still not working correctly. As u've added fn in useEffect dependency array so it is attaching wheel event on everytime fn updates. The reason I left this array empty is this useEffect will only run once on mount and unmount listener after when unmounting occur as I've added return in useEffect.